# Direct access to Jest equality test

Tags: jestjs

Using Jest you can easily do a deep comparison two objects:

```
expect(requestBody).toEqual(expectedRequest);
```

Is there any way to use *that same equality test* programmatically without triggering an assertion? Something like

```
const matches = isEqual(requestBody, expectedRequest);
```

This would be very useful to write predicates in unit tests. E.g. to make Angulars `HttpTestingController` watch for a specific request body it would be nice to just write

```
  httpController.expectOne(request => isEqual(request.body, expectedRequest));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jest matcher functions aren't exposed. In case there's a need for deep equality check, Lodash/Underscore `isEqual` can be used directly [which is used by Jest](https://github.com/facebook/jest/blob/v25.5.2/packages/expect/src/jasmineUtils.ts#L63-L64).

It's possible to catch assertion error:

```
isEqual = (a, b) => {
  try {
    expect(a).toEqual(b);
    return true;
  } catch (err) {
    if (e.matcherResult)
      return false;

    throw err;
  }
};
```

Jest can be possibly integrated with `HttpTestingController` by defining [custom matcher](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/expect#custom-matchers-api) that has the access to `equals`.

Comment: Great answer! Thanks in particular for the link to the Jest source code. I guess I'll go for the _catch assertion error_ implementation for now, and switch to the _lodash implementation_ once I need this more often.